# Streaming Flash Video Problem - Clipping

Tags: flash, video, streaming, clipping

I have a simple flash video player that streams the video from a streaming media server.  The stream plays fine and I have no problems with playing the video and doing simple functions.  However, my problem is that on a mouse over of the video, I have the controls come up and when I do a seek or scrub on the video, I get little weird boxes that show over the video - like little pockets - of the video playing super fast (you can basically see it seeking) until it gets to the point it needs to be at and then these little boxes disappear.  Is anybody else having these problems and if so, how do I fix this?  I thought it might be some kind of masking problem, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

That's strange; I've never seen anything like that. If you're using the built-in FLVPlayback control, my money is on the problem being a server-side configuration issue. Otherwise, try it with the [FLVPlayback](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html) control.

Also, make sure you don't have any other graphics of any kind behind/infront of the video on the stage.

Best of luck!

Edit: Try calling NetStream.pause() before you call seek.

Comment: Yeah, it is really strange.  I'm not using the FLVPlayback control though.  I'm using the NetStream with a video object.  Not sure if this helps, but here is the code I use when scrubbing:

var mc = vidControls.seekerBar.scrubBar;
var dist:Number = mc._xmouse/mc._width;
ns.seek(Math.floor(ns.duration*dist));

Not sure why this would cause this weird effect though.

Comment: It was a good idea about the pausing of the netstream before seeking, but still it didn't work.  Here's a link to an image to better explain the problem I'm confronting.  http://www.seguemedia.com/flvScrubbing.jpg  Any other thoughts?

Comment: It looks like the transparent parts of the "Rendering" box aren't updating quickly enough. Try setting that to .visible = false.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.  What is the "rendering" box though.  I guess I'm not sure what I'm supposed to apply the ".visible = false" to.  I dynamically create a video object, and apply the netstream to that object.  I don't think setting the object to visible = false is the correct solution.